# How do I launch a Power Point slide show on startup?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

I want to launch a Power Point presentation on startup - in slide show mode (I don't want to simply open the file).

This is to run on a kiosk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Microsoft's list of [command line switches](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint/HA101538891033.aspx), you can use the`/S` switch to start a presentation:

```
C:\path\to\POWERPNT.exe" /S "Presentation.pptx"
```

To get the slideshow to start on boot-up create a shortcut to the path given above and put it in the **Startup** folder in the Start menu.

Answer (score 1):

you can also rename the file to pps or ppsx. this should make the presentation go immediately in presentation mode.